# MVVM ListView MultiBinding SelectedItems + SelectedItem (ListView) + SelectedItem (ComboBox) to TextBox.Text. Does not update properly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, multibinding

I am trying to MultiBind the `SelectedItems` (ListView) and `SelectedItem` or SelectedCategory in my ViewModel (ComboBox) to a readonly `TextBox`. The OutputConverter just checks if there is at least one item selected (ListView) and TypeData (ComboBox) selected before creating the text for the `TextBox`.

However, if I try it only with that the `TextBox` only updates when the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` changes not when `SelectedItems` inside ListView changes.
So I also included from my ViewModel `SelectedEntry` (ListView) (which is same as `SelectedItem`) as a Binding for the MultiBinding.

Now I get the following:

[image]

**Explanation:**
The Selection is always one step behind and uses the previous `SelectedItems` from the ListView to bind to the `TextBox.Text`. Even when I am selecting multiple entries via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>. However, if the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` changes it updates the `TextBox` as intended.

How do I get the behaviour if the Selection changes inside the ListView the `TextBox` immediately updates its content accordingly (preferably I would like to use the `SelectedEntries` of my ViewModel and not the `SelectedItems` of the ListView and if possible in a MVVM compliant way)?

**Edit:**

- I noticed when the Converter is called the SelectedEntry (implements
  INotifyPropertyChanged) is updated but the SelectedEntries
  (ObservableCollection and implements INotifyPropertyChanged) is not.
- I have also included a SelectionChanged event that calls a command
  and passes the SelectedItems as a parameter to the command. If that
  might help but I would rather like to have a proper binding that
  updates accordingly.

---

### Code:

**Model TypeData (ComboBox):**

```
public class TypeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum Type
    {
        NotSet = '0',
        A = 'A',
        B = 'B',
        C = 'C'
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
    private Type category;

    public Type Category
    {
        get { return category; }
        set { category = value; }
    }


    public TypeData(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**Model Entry (ListView):**

```
public class Entry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        }
    }

    private string author;

    public string Author
    {
        get { return author; }
        set
        {
            author = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Author));
        }
    }

    private string year;

    public string Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set
        {
            year = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Year));
        }
    }


    public Entry(string title, string author, string year)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Year = year;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    public Entry SelectedEntry { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Entry> SelectedEntries { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TypeData> Types { get; set; }

    private TypeData selectedCategory;

    public TypeData SelectedCategory { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand<object> SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Entries = new ObservableCollection<Entry>
        {
            new Entry("Title1", "Author1", "Year1"),
            new Entry("Title2", "Author2", "Year2"),
            new Entry("Title3", "Author3", "Year3"),
            new Entry("Title4", "Author4", "Year4"),
        };

        Types = new ObservableCollection<TypeData>
        {
            new TypeData("A"),
            new TypeData("B"),
            new TypeData("C"),
        };

        SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(items =>
        {
            var selectedEntries = (items as ObservableCollection<object>).Cast<Entry>();
            SelectedEntries = new ObservableCollection<Entry>(selectedEntries);
        });
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmMultiBinding.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmMultiBinding"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MvvmMultiBinding.Model"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmMultiBinding.ViewModel"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MvvmMultiBinding.View.Converter"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel></vm:MainViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:OutputConverter x:Key="OutputConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListView Name="ListViewEntries" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Author" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Year" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, ElementName=ListViewEntries}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=ListViewEntries}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListView>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" MinWidth="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OutputConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="ListViewEntries" Path="SelectedItems" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <!--<Binding Path="SelectedEntries" Mode="OneWay"/>-->
                    <Binding Path="SelectedCategory" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <!-- Without it converter is not called after selection changes -->
                    <Binding Path="SelectedEntry" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </DockPanel> 
</Grid>
```

**OutputConverter:**

```
public class OutputConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Collections.IList items = (System.Collections.IList)values[0];
        var entries = items.Cast<Entry>();
        TypeData type = values[1] as TypeData;
        List<Entry> selectedEntries = new List<Entry>();

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            selectedEntries.Add(entry);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // ComboBox and Selection must not be empty
        if (type != null && selectedEntries.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var selectedEntry in selectedEntries)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}\n\n", selectedEntry.Author, type);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The MainViewModel should implement INotifyPropertChanged so SelectedEntry etc. will raise the correct events

Comment: I see seems cleaner. But how would I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged for IEnumerable items e.g. SelectedEntries (that is also an ObserverableCollection) inside the ViewModel?

Comment: I would add a property on the Entry class named IsSelected and bind it to the View of the Entry (Checkbox.IsChecked or similar) then the SelectedEntries becomes redundant or a simple Linq expression .....Where(e=>e.IsSelected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest giving your Entry Class an IsSelected property (Bound to the IsSelectedProperty of a ListViewItem). When the selection changes you can just iterate through your collection (bound to the ListView) and check if they are selected or not. Like this (excuse the MvvmLight, RelayCommand = ICommand, ViewModelBase extends ObservableObject):

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TestItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>
        {
            new TestItem("Test1"),
             new TestItem("Test2"),
              new TestItem("Test3")
            };
    }

    private TestItem m_selectedItemProperty;
    public TestItem SelectedItemProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return m_selectedItemProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            m_selectedItemProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItemProperty");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItemCollection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelayCommand SelectionChanged
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(OnSelectionChanged); }
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged()
    {
        foreach (var item in TestItemCollection)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected)
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

I printed the names out here but you can also just add them to a string property and bind it to your text box or add the items to a collection (maybe bound to a ListBox or ItemsControl showing the selected entries).

**TestItem:**

```
public class TestItem : ObservableObject
{
    public TestItem(string a_name)
    {
        m_name = a_name;
    }

    private string m_name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private bool m_isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return m_isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            m_isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppTests"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:modelNoMvvmLight="clr-namespace:WpfAppTests"
    xmlns:modelMvvmLight="clr-namespace:WpfAppTests.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Window.DataContext>
    <modelMvvmLight:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TestItemCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemProperty}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" >
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: The idea to have a property with the designated text bound to the `TextBox.Text` instead of a Converter really helped me here. The only downside in this case is I have to updated this property when the selection of the ListView and the selection of the ComboBox changes inside the corresponding set methods in order to reflect the changes. Whereas if I were using the MultiBind and the Converter I would not need this. Thank you.